# Java LDAP with SASL

Tags: java, ldap, sasl

I am using Java 1.2 with the Netscape ldapjdk.jar and trying to make an LDAP connection to one of our servers that needs SASL.  I’m also relativity new to LDAP.  I do know that java EE has built in LDAP but I am not able to use it at this time.

I have been able to make a connection to another server using regular LDAP but I am not sure what I need to put into the parameters.  If someone has a simple example that would be helpful.

I think the class below is what I need to use:

```
String ldapUserDn = "cn=mycomputer,dc=Dcname";      
String[]  mechanisms = {"DIGEST-MD5"};
LDAPSaslBind saslBind = new LDAPSaslBind(
   String ldapUserDn, 
   mechanisms, 
   String packageName, 
   Hashtable props, 
   Object cbh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java EE would normally utilise JNDI for LDAP connections instead of the Netscape API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/sasl.html